# WPF Desktop Application for Bar Code Reader

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode-scanner

Do I have to make a WPF desktop application if I want to provide bar code scanner facility or it will work well with Web application?

Comment: A barcode scanner typically presents itself as a keyboard. It will type in the barcode value and send the code for the return key.

Comment: Providing you're scanner is in *wedge mode*, and you can make your *cursor* be at the right position in the web-page, its fine

Comment: this is offtopic, you may do whatever better fits your needs

Answer (score 2):

Providing your scanner is in *Keyboard wedge mode*, and you can make your cursor be at the right position in the web-page, it's fine.

---

**Additional resources**

[keyboard wedge (KBW)](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/keyboard-wedge-KBW)

> A keyboard wedge can be either a software program or an inserted
>   hardware device that translates digital signals from a barcode reader
>   or magnetic strip reader ( MSR ) into keyboard strokes for a computer.
>
> The software form of a keyboard wedge intercepts the dignal signals
>   from the reader when they arrive at the computer and instantly
>   translates them into keyboard strokes.
>
> The hardware form of a keyboard wedge inserts the translation device
>   between the reader and the keyboard. Data sent through a wedge appears
>   as if it was typed into the computer, while the keyboard itself
>   remains fully functional.
>
> Because a computer using a keyboard wedge can't tell the difference
>   between data that is entered by a scanning device, or data that is
>   entered by keyboard typing, a wedge can be used to easily add barcode
>   reading capability to an existing computer without modifying software
>   applications.